# Display certain <li> together on one row and the rest <li> one per row

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display all `<li>` with ID = 13502 on 1 row and all the rest of `<li>` listed each per row. That last one is working but I can't get the 4 `<li>` with ID = 13502 listed on 1 row.

HTML:

```
    <div id="side-header">
    <nav class="fusion-main-menu" aria-label="Main Menu">
    <ul role="menubar" id="menu-main-menu-de" class="fusion-menu">
    <li role="menuitem" id="menu-item-13502-nl" class="lang-item lang-item-33 lang-item-nl lang-item-first menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13502-nl" data-classes="lang-item"></li>
    <li role="menuitem" id="menu-item-13502-en" class="lang-item lang-item-37 lang-item-en menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13502-en" data-classes="lang-item"></li>
    <li role="menuitem" id="menu-item-13502-de" class="lang-item lang-item-30 lang-item-de current-lang menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-13502-de" data-classes="lang-item"></li>
    <li role="menuitem" id="menu-item-13502-fr" class="lang-item lang-item-41 lang-item-fr menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13502-fr" data-classes="lang-item"></li>
    <li role="menuitem" id="menu-item-13693" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-13549 current_page_item menu-item-13693">
    <a href="http://example.com/de/home-de/" class="fusion-flex-link"><span class="fusion-megamenu-icon"><i class="fa glyphicon fa-home fa-fw"></i></span><span class="menu-text">Home</span></a></li>
    <li role="menuitem" id="menu-item-13588" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13588">
    <a href="http://example.com/de/finde-geschaftspartner/"><span class="menu-text">Finde Geschäftspartner</span></a></li>
    <li role="menuitem" id="menu-item-13898" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13898">
    <a href="http://example.com/de/finde-wiederverkaufer/"><span class="menu-text">Finde Wiederverkäufer</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#side-header .fusion-main-menu #menu-item-13502-nl,
#side-header .fusion-main-menu #menu-item-13502-de,
#side-header .fusion-main-menu #menu-item-13502-en,
#side-header .fusion-main-menu #menu-item-13502-fr{
 list-style-type:none;
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
}
```

Comment: Is there enough space for all items to fit in? You can also try using `display: inline-block` instead of float.

Comment: yes. its only a flag icon. So 4 flag icons at 1 row will be the result.
Max-width : 230px; in total

Comment: In that case you will have to use browser inspector to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float: left;` with `display:inline;`. Check this:

```css
#side-header .fusion-main-menu #menu-item-13502-nl,
#side-header .fusion-main-menu #menu-item-13502-de,
#side-header .fusion-main-menu #menu-item-13502-en,
#side-header .fusion-main-menu #menu-item-13502-fr{
 list-style-type:none;
 list-style: none;
 display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="side-header">
  <nav class="fusion-main-menu" aria-label="Main Menu">
    <ul role="menubar" id="menu-main-menu-de" class="fusion-menu">
      <li role="menuitem" id="menu-item-13502-nl" class="lang-item lang-item-33 lang-item-nl lang-item-first menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13502-nl" data-classes="lang-item">A</li>
      <li role="menuitem" id="menu-item-13502-en" class="lang-item lang-item-37 lang-item-en menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13502-en" data-classes="lang-item">B</li>
      <li role="menuitem" id="menu-item-13502-de" class="lang-item lang-item-30 lang-item-de current-lang menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-13502-de" data-classes="lang-item">C</li>
      <li role="menuitem" id="menu-item-13502-fr" class="lang-item lang-item-41 lang-item-fr menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13502-fr" data-classes="lang-item">D</li>
      <li role="menuitem" id="menu-item-13693" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-13549 current_page_item menu-item-13693">
        <a href="http://example.com/de/home-de/" class="fusion-flex-link"><span class="fusion-megamenu-icon"><i class="fa glyphicon fa-home fa-fw"></i></span><span class="menu-text">Home</span></a></li>
      <li role="menuitem" id="menu-item-13588" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13588">
        <a href="http://example.com/de/finde-geschaftspartner/"><span class="menu-text">Finde Geschäftspartner</span></a></li>
      <li role="menuitem" id="menu-item-13898" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13898">
        <a href="http://example.com/de/finde-wiederverkaufer/"><span class="menu-text">Finde Wiederverkäufer</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: @Hermants, that's probably because there are other styles in your css too. Please add them to your question. Otherwise you can't be helped.

Comment: Then I have to search in the css code of fusion. THat is a huge file. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Hermants, then just inspect the `<li>` elements and find the styles that they have.